# Assign values with same name in a nested list in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

I want to assign the same value to specific elements in nested lists that have the same name. I would also like to create the element if it didn't exist in the nested list, but this isn't shown in my example.

For example, let's say I have:

```
ls <- list(a = list(e1 = "value1.1", e2 = "value1.2"),
           b = list(e1 = "value2.1", e2 = "value2.2"))
```

And I want to assign the value "same value" to all the elements in sublists that are named `e1` so that I would end up with this **desired output:**

```
list(a = list(e1 = "same value", e2 = "value1.2"),
     b = list(e1 = "same value", e2 = "value2.2")
> ls
  $a
  $a$e1
  [1] "same value"

  $a$e2
  [1] "value1.2"


  $b
  $b$e1
  [1] "same value"

  $b$e2
  [1] "value2.2"
```

After researches, I found the function `modify_depth()` in the package `purrr` that will apply a function to the nested lists, but won't assign a value.

My only other solution was to do this:

```
ls2 <- list()
for(sublist in ls){
  sublist[["e1"]] <- "same value"
  ls2 <- c(ls2, list(sublist))
}
names(ls2) <- names(ls)
ls <- ls2
rm(ls2)
```

Note: after the loop, "same value" are not assigned in ls, so I have to create `ls2`. I could make this a function, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this, without a `for` loop.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `map` and `replace` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
map(ls, ~replace(., "e1", "same value"))
```

or with `modify_depth`:

```
modify_depth(ls, 1, ~replace(., "e1", "same value"))
```

`replace` also works with `lapply`:

```
lapply(ls, replace, "e1", "same value")
```

**Output:**

```
$a
$a$e1
[1] "same value"

$a$e2
[1] "value1.2"


$b
$b$e1
[1] "same value"

$b$e2
[1] "value2.2"
```

The good thing about `modify_depth` is that you can choose the depth, whereas `map` and `lapply` only goes down one level:

```
ls2 <- list(c = list(a1 = list(e1 = "value1.1", e2 = "value1.2")),
            d = list(a1 = list(e1 = "value2.1", e2 = "value2.2")))

modify_depth(ls2, 2, ~replace(., "e1", "same value"))
```

**Output:**

```
$c
$c$a1
$c$a1$e1
[1] "same value"

$c$a1$e2
[1] "value1.2"


$d
$d$a1
$d$a1$e1
[1] "same value"

$d$a1$e2
[1] "value2.2"
```

**Edit:** If we want to apply a vector of values to each `e1` element of `ls2`, `modify_depth` would not work since it does not have a `map2` variant. Instead, I would use two layers of `map`'s, `map2` on the top layer, and `map` on the second layer.

```
vec <- c("newvalue1.1", "newvalue2.1")

map2(ls2, vec, ~map(.x, replace, "e1", .y))
```

**Output:**

```
$c
$c$a1
$c$a1$e1
[1] "newvalue1.1"

$c$a1$e2
[1] "value1.2"


$d
$d$a1
$d$a1$e1
[1] "newvalue2.1"

$d$a1$e2
[1] "value2.2"
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for clarification:

What does the `~` mean before `replace`? What does it do?
And if we go further, knowing the number and order of my sublists, is it possible to use a vector of different values, instead of `"same value"`?

Comment: @AParent `~` is a shorthand for creating an anonymous function like `function(x)`. It allows you to use the `.` instead of `x` as input argument. It depends on what you mean by "use a vector of different values". Are you saying with a vector of different strings, replace each first element of the list with the corresponding elements in the vector?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be clearer: If I use your list `ls2`, I meant I would like to assign something like `"newvalue1.1"` to `c$a1$e1` and `"newvalue2.1"` to `d$a1$e1`. So instead of using `"same value"`, I would like to use `c("newvalue1.1", "newvalue1.2")`. But I don't want the whole vector to be assigned to `c$a1$e1`, only the first element, and so on.

Comment: @AParent Unfortunately, `modify_depth` does not seem to have a `map2` variant, so we can't map `ls2` and `vec` at the same time. See my update for an alternative using `map2` and `map`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to iterate over list elements, then using `[` with logical operator for equality `==` we can locate the values we want to change

```
> lapply(ls, function(x){
    x[names(x)=="e1"] <- "same.value"
    x
  } )
$`a`
$`a`$`e1`
[1] "same.value"

$`a`$e2
[1] "value1.2"


$b
$b$`e1`
[1] "same.value"

$b$e2
[1] "value2.2"
```

Comment: Since OP says "I would also like to create the element if it didn't exist in the nested list, but this isn't shown in my example.", could skip checking of names. `lapply(L, \`[[<-\`, "e1", "same value")` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

`ls` is reserved in R so I suggest to use another name for the list, my alternative is:

```
y <- list(a = list(e1 = "value1.1", e2 = "value1.2"),
           b = list(e1 = "value2.1", e2 = "value2.2"))

lapply(y, function(x) replace(x, list = "e1", values = "new value"))

$a
$a$e1
[1] "new value"

$a$e2
[1] "value1.2"


$b
$b$e1
[1] "new value"

$b$e2
[1] "value2.2"
```