# How to Set Names for Nested Lists in R of Depth 5

Tags: r, tidyverse, nested-lists

I'm working with a deeply nested list structure in R, and I'm having trouble setting names for lists at a depth of 5. I've managed to do it for lists of depth 4, but I'm unsure how to proceed further. Here's a reproducible example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create fake data
set.seed(1234)
data <- tibble(
    category1 = rep(letters[1:4], each = 25),
    category2 = sample(letters[5:9], size = 100, replace = T),
    category3 = sample(letters[10:14], size = 100, replace = T),
    some_variable = rnorm(100)
)

# Create the first named list of tibbles with assigned names (depth = 3)
nested_data1 <- data %>% 
    nest(.by = category1) %>%
    pull(data) %>% 
    setNames(unique(data$category1))

# Create a list of vectors of names for layer 3 
category2_by_category1 <- nested_data1 %>% 
    map(~pull(., "category2")) %>% 
    map(~unique(.))

# Create the second list of tibbles with assigned names (depth = 4)
nested_data2 <- nested_data1 %>% 
    map(~nest(., .by = "category2")) %>% 
    map(~pull(., data)) %>% 
    map2(category2_by_category1, ~set_names(.x, .y))

# Create a list of lists of vectors of names for layer 4
category3_by_category2_by_category1 <- nested_data2 %>% 
    map_depth(2, ~ pull(., "category3")) %>% 
    map_depth(2, ~ unique(.))

# Create the third list of tibbles without assigned names (depth = 5)
nested_data3 <- nested_data2 %>% 
    map_depth(2, ~ nest(., .by = "category3")) %>% 
    map_depth(2, ~ pull(., data))

# This line is the problem
map2(nested_data3, category3_by_category2_by_category1, ~map_depth(2, ~set_names(.x, .y)))
```

I want to set the names of the innermost lists to the element listed in depth 3 of `category3_by_category2_by_category1`. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

This last line of code is my best try based on the answer of acylam to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192776/assign-values-with-same-name-in-a-nested-list-in-r)

Here's the error message I get when I try to run the last line of code :

```
Error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: a.
Caused by error in `map_depth()`:
! `depth` must be a whole number, not a <formula> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Xavier! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this *really* the best way of storing your data? Putting 1x1 dataframes inside 5 layers of nested lists? It seems like you're just making it hard for yourself

Comment: Hi Mark! Creating a hierarchical structure of lists leading up to a tibble is more convenient than it seems even tho it does seem very complex at first. I'm working with correlations that are defined by many categorical variables. Sometimes, the unique combination of every categorical variables lead to more than one observation so I didn't want to resort to concatenating strings.

Comment: couldn't you just add these things as columns?

Comment: I guess you're right. A new column of concatenated string would allow to filter the dataframe just the same. However, I do like to make things hard for myself so this is a bummer haha

Comment: I tried something like that. But at the end it repeats the 1st variable: `map2(nested_data3, category3_by_category2_by_category1, \(x,y) (map_depth(x,2,\(x)(SetNames(x,pluck(y,1))))))`

Comment: For example you want for  `nested_data3$d$e` the name 1st column of each sub dataframe, named `some_variable`, became the names in `category3_by_category2_by_category1$d$e` ie  `nested_data3$d$e[[1]]` some_variable will become `n`,  `nested_data3$d$e[[2]]` some_variable will become `k`,  `nested_data3$d$e[[3]]` some_variable will become `l` ?

Comment: with the value of `category3_by_category2_by_category1$d$e` is `c("n", "k", "l")` and `nested_data3$d$e[[1]]` some_variable 1.06  and 1.48, `nested_data3$d$e[[2]]` some_variable -1.14 , `nested_data3$d$e[[2]]` some_variable 0.258  will become  `nested_data3$d$e[[1]]` n 1.06  and 1.48, `nested_data3$d$e[[2]]` k -1.14 , `nested_data3$d$e[[2]]` l 0.258   ?

Comment: I don't think this is right. I want the names of the dataframes in `nested_data3$d$e` to become the values of `category3_by_category2_by_category1$d$e` if that makes sens. So to refer to any of the dataframes in `nested_data3$d$e` I could use the `$` operator and choose the name of the specific dataframe I'm interested in without having to remember the indexes, like `nested_data3$d$e$n`. It would also make iterative calling easier, making it possible to do things like `nested_data3[[paste0(category1[i])]][[paste0(category2[j])]][[paste0(category3[k])]]`.

Comment: Xavire re: `A new column of concatenated string` - I wasn't suggesting that! You should have one column for each layer

Comment: Like, I have done janky things before, like nesting three layers of `map` calls, and while it is *possible*, it's much simpler and easier to add a `.by = c(col1, col2, etc.)` onto the end of a mutate than it is to do that